# MySQL Api: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: c++, mysql

There are zillions of these questions I know, but none of them were similar to my issue, so I figured I'd ask.  I have a server set up that validates clients that connect to it by receiving username/password combinations and checking them using a SQL query.  I wrote the system, and it worked perfectly fine during the first couple of requests.

http://puu.sh/d9mss/384b4df9f0.png

However, I found that if I wait about 5 minutes and then try to connect, this happens.

http://puu.sh/d9mx7/192cbb2cfc.png

This is the code that I am running to perform that task.

```
bool CNetDatabase::AuthUser(std::string username, const unsigned char* passwordhash)
{
RoughSanitizeString(username);      //this doesn't do anything


/* Turn password hash into string */
std::ostringstream password;
password.fill('0');
password << std::hex;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    password << std::setw(2) << (unsigned int)passwordhash[i];
}


/* Make request */
MYSQL_RES* result = nullptr;
if (mysql_query(sql_con, tools::string::format(
    "SELECT COUNT(`index`) FROM `Users` WHERE `username` = '%s' AND `password` = '%s'", 
    username.c_str(), password.str().c_str()).c_str()))
{
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "ERROR: mysql_query failed: %s  [%d]\n",
        mysql_error(sql_con), mysql_errno(sql_con));

    return false;
}


/* Get and return result */
result = mysql_store_result(sql_con);
MYSQL_ROW row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
mysql_free_result(result);
return row[0][0] == '1' ? true : false;
}
```

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Comment: No need to include textual output as images. Just copy it into your post and format as 'code'; insert `<!-- language: lang-none -->` on a separate line before it to make it ignore syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I think it's safe to conclude that it is my host's problem, not my code.  I registered an account with a site that offered the ability to make free MySQL databases, and my server has been throwing SQL queries at it without issue all night.  For posterity, if you are using your website's SQL server and are hosting with Hostgator, they might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html). There are session timeouts on both client and server side.

Anyway it is a good practice to expect that connection to external resources may become unavailable and try to reconnect (for instance database server could be physically rebooted). You can try to set `reconnect` flag when creating connection to enable automatic reconnects but those might not always work depending on your environment.

Comment: Did so, only problem is that it only resets after the failed attempt.  This means the user would need to make the request twice in order to log in.  I'm beginning to suspect this is my host's problem and not mine, going to test on a local sql database and post back later.